# Is it possible to monitor kafka producer/consumer metrics in DCOS?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, confluent-platform, mesosphere, dcos

I am trying to do this without using Confluent Control Center, since I do not have a license.

I am able to see the Kafka Broker metrics by using `dcos task metrics details <broker-id>` and see that all of these are already exposed on my DCOS Prometheus instance.

However, I do not see any consumer/producer metrics available on Prometheus, despite having some producers/consumer tasks on dcos.

Is there a process I can follow to expose kafka prodcuer/consumer metrics on dcos? I tried the following https://github.com/ibm-cloud-architecture/refarch-eda/blob/master/docs/kafka/monitoring.md .

But from my understanding we cannot use JMX on a Kafka instance hosted on DCOS (yet) (soruce: https://jira.mesosphere.com/browse/DCOS_OSS-3632?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add Prometheus JMX exporters to each of your Kafka Java processes, and then you would need to have the Prometheus server be able to scrape those. You would do this by downloading that JAR in each of the processes (containers?), then editing the `KAFKA_OPTS` environment varible to include the `-javaagent` option

AFAIK, this does not require setting up a remotely accessible JMX port.

Note: Control Center doesn't monitor JMX values. It uses Kafka MetricsReporters and Interceptors. Use of these interfaces, if you chose to write your own, or find others, doesn't require Control Center at all.